# How to use sed to modify last 3 digit of a line with random number when a string matches in a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have a file 'a.txt' which have a content:

```
K8A2-19C204-BA109691  
ML_18.10.4-109691
```

How can i search for a string say "ML_" in the file and if it matches modify last 3 digit of that line with some random numbers using 'sed' command in bash script.
I am able to change the last 3 numbers to some fixed numbers with the command:

```
sed -i '/ML_/s/[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/012/' file_name
```

But not sure how to change with random numbers

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any particular requirements for the randomness, then you can use the bash shell's built in `RANDOM` as mentioned in comments e.g.

```
$ sed '/^ML_/ s/[0-9]\{3\}$/'$(printf '%03d' $((RANDOM%1000)))'/' a.txt 
K8A2-19C204-BA109691
ML_18.10.4-109133
```

If you require "better" random numbers, then I'd suggest abandoning `sed` in favor of `perl` and looking for a suitable random number module.